# File editor is too small at files in pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

The height is only two lines after running a file when it is focused. A white rectangle is below and next the console window is below it. When being lost focus , it is covered partial by the console window. How can I get the editor to be bigger?

The account I have is free account :(
I access the page on smartphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PythonAnywhere doesn't really work that well on smartphones right now -- only on desktop computers and iPads.